# Should GraphQL request for calculated object be mutation or query?

Tags: graphql

`CreateCustomer` is clearly a mutation.

`GetCustomer` is clearly a query.

But what would be some `CalculateProductPriceForThisAmazingCustomer`?

Is it a query, because no price is stored (no data written), it is just calculated?

Or is it a mutation, because price was not stored anywhere previously, we are "creating" it in memory?

Comment: Some things you call clear are not that clear at all :-)

Comment: ""creating" it in memory?" - by that logic everything would be a mutation, as even the most basic query is going to generate all kinds of temporary things in memory, just reading your request from the network has to modify memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GraphQL, query vs mutation doesn't matter that much.

With different API technologies like REST there are substantial differences between methods like GET or POST. For example, there are differences in how requests can be cached or retried.

The [difference between a GraphQL query vs mutation lies mostly in how the resolvers are executed](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/):

- **Queries** are not supposed to change state and can therefore be safely executed **concurrently**.
- **Mutations** can affect state. In order to get predictable results, mutation resolvers are evaluated in order / **serially**.

There are no further technical differences. That some things tend to be expressed as a mutation is more of a convention, but in principle it would also be possible to use queries for state-changing operations.

Because mutations run serially, they tend to be slower. This is a motivation to use GraphQL queries whenever appropriate.

Your `CalculateProductPriceForThisAmazingCustomer` field sounds very much like it should be available in queries, not just in mutations. The result of other fields won't depend on when this field is calculated, so concurrent evaluation would be possible.

In contrast, `CreateCustomer` should be a mutation because there's a clear before – after relationship. Consider the following query:

```
query {
  CreateCustomer(id: 1234) { id },
  GetCustomer(id: 1234) { id }
}
```

Due to concurrent execution, the result of that query would not be deterministic.

- If CreateCustomer finishes before GetCustomer is resolved, we would get a result.
- Otherwise, we would get an error.

But if that query were changed to a mutation, we would always get a deterministic result.